# How can I annotate my helper method so Eclipse knows its argument is non null if it returns true?

Tags: java, eclipse, null, annotations

I have a helper method, `hasContent(String)`, which returns true iff its argument is both non-null and contains at least one non-whitespace character. I have just enabled null analysis in Eclipse and I have found that when I use this method to execute a block of code which is conditional on the result of my helper function indicating that the string has content (and therefore **cannot** be null), that nonetheless Eclipse complains that my String might still be null.

**The helper function**

```
public static boolean hasContent(String text) {
    if (text == null)
        return false;
    if (text.trim().length() == 0)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

**Example of use**

```
...
String dataString;

try {
    dataString = readStringFromFile("somefile.txt");
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Failed to read file due to error: " + e);
    dataString = null;
}

// At this point dataString may be null

if (hasContent(dataString)) {

    // At this point dataString must be non-null, but Eclipse warns:
    // "Potential null pointer access: The variable dataString may be null at this location"
    // at the following reference to dataString

    System.out.println("Read string length " + dataString.length());
}
...
```

What is the best practice for this situation? I don't want to suppress the warning if I can avoid it. I'd prefer to tell Eclipse that if `hasContent()` returns `true` then it's argument is definately non-null. Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contract of your method is that if `hasContent` returns true, then its argument is guaranteed to be non-null.

Eclipse cannot express or check this contract at compile time, at least without changing your code and degrading its style.

The [Nullness Checker](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#nullness-checker) is a different tool that can express and check this contract at compile time.  It does so without requiring you to change your code.  You simply add the [`@EnsuresNonNullIf`](https://checkerframework.org/api/org/checkerframework/checker/nullness/qual/EnsuresNonNullIf.html) annotation your code:

```
@EnsuresNonNullIf(expression="#1", result=true)
public static boolean hasContent(String text) { ...
```

The Nullness Checker is distributed with the [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/).
There is an [Eclipse plugin](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#eclipse) that enables you to run the Nullness Checker within Eclipse.

Comment: Thank you mernst, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the best practice, but: If an IOException is thrown, you can return false, or simply set a variable to false. If not, you can set the variable to true (in the try-block).

```
try {
    dataString = readStringFromFile("somefile.txt");
    hasContent = true;
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Failed to read file due to error: " + e);
    hasContent = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this misses the point of my question. I could certainly simply test: `if (dataString != null) { do stuff with dataString }` and this would probably not be flagged by eclipse. But I want a way to tell eclipse that `if (hasContent(dataString)) { do stuff with dataString }` is at least as safe as the above.

Comment: Well what you want to do would require a default parameter, but Java does not support that.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see a way to do exactly what you are attempting.

You could modify `hasContent` to return the string it is passed, rather than the a `boolean` and throw an `Exception` if the argument is null or empty. You would then annotate the function with `@NonNull`. This would however compromise your calling code in a way that I suspect you would not like since it would have to use `try`/`catch` logic rather than an `if`.

This would make the `hasContent` function:

```
@NonNull
public static String hasContent(String text) throws Exception {
    if (text == null)
        throw new Exception( "Null string" );
    if (text.trim().length() == 0)
        throw new Exception( "Empty string" );
    return text;        
}
```

and the calling code:

```
...
try {
    dataString = readStringFromFile("somefile.txt");
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Failed to read file due to error: " + e);
    dataString = null;
}

// At this point dataString may be null
try {
    dataString = validateHasContent( dataString );
    // At this point dataString must be non-null

    System.out.println("Read string length " + dataString.length());
} catch( Exception e ) {        
}
...
```

If you were prepared to make this compromise then a dedicated exception would clearly be better.