# Eclipse null check doesn't work with functions

Tags: java, eclipse

I am getting a `Potential null pointer access: The variable test may be null at this location` eclipse warning from the below code.

```
public class Runtime {

    public static void main(final String args[]) throws Exception {
        Collection<String> test = null;
        if (new Random().nextBoolean()) {
            test = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        if (!isNullOrEmpty(test)) {
            test.size();
        }
    }

    public static boolean isNullOrEmpty(final Collection<?> coll) {
        return (coll == null) || coll.isEmpty();
    }

}
```

The act of checking isNullOrEmpty should guarantee that test is non-null. Making the function call inline will fix the problem, proving that this is just an eclipse limitation.

I don't want to ignore the warning, because I need to know if I forget to do the check, and I don't want to inline the same check 500 times (especially the more complex cases).

Is there anyway to adjust this so that eclipse knows test is not null when I call size?

I am using Java 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?
[How can I annotate my helper method so Eclipse knows its argument is non null if it returns true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43611344/how-can-i-annotate-my-helper-method-so-eclipse-knows-its-argument-is-non-null-if)

Apparently (I have never use it) you can annotate the helper method with something like:

```
 @EnsuresNonNullIf(expression="#1", result=true)
 public static boolean isNullOrEmpty(final Collection<?> coll) { ...
```

It may require an add-on..

Comment: This is a solution... though it requires the Checker Framework. which looks complicated to setup. I was kinda hoping there is a configuration or plugin to do this. ^^;

Answer (score 1):

It **really** looks like you wanted an [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) instead of a `Collection`. In which case, you could use one. Like,

```
Optional<String> optional = Optional.ofNullable(null);
if (new Random().nextBoolean()) {
    optional = Optional.of("somevalue");
}
if (optional.isPresent()) {
    System.out.println(optional.get());
}
```

Comment: `Optional.ofNullable(null)` can be shorted to `Optional.empty()`.

Comment: No.. collection is what I want because I want to process a list of values. The type of test isn't really important though, just that it is safe to call methods from it. Since `optional.get().length();` will throw a null pointer exception if I fail to call `isPresent()` first, this seems more like a verbose way of setting the null pointer flag to ignore. Which is not the behavior I want. If I remembered to check things before using them, I wouldn't need the null pointer flag in the first place. ^^;